# Why is marriage so important?

Tags: nikah, practical-islam, sharia, love

In Islam you cant have relationships out of marriage because it may lead to Zina. Why cant there be any love or relationships outside marriage? Lets say that you are completely devoted to someone and the same vice versa why cant this relationship be permissible?

Ive seen some people say that in marriage there is responsibility, that doesn't mean there isnt outside marriage.

Also some may not want to have kids or marriage may be hard this could be due to the wali (the wali may want a very rich person and the person may not have a nice personality or the woman getting married may not have a wali at all) or the person may not be financially stable or whatever other reasons.
In marrriage it doesnt protect you from contracting sexual diseases either.
People can break up in marriages just as they can outside marriages.

Ive also seen that marriage can be helpful for the economy but the same can be said with relationships outside marriage. If they were permisible and lets say that you werent allowed to have more than one relationship itd basically be the same.

Also outside marriage relationships can help find whether you will truly be able to love that person for the rest of your life. In Islam you cant have contact with the woman/man you are going to marry so you dont know whether they will be able to keep you happy or if they have a nice personality.

So what is the difference between relationships in marriage and outside that makes marriage so important?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't have love outside marriage is because sexual love is there to fulfill a noble purpose in creation as set by Allah, that is, so that couples can form long term relations, procreate and raise their children. This is only possible in a long term sexual and emotional commitment, called marriage, and codified by Islam as nikah.

But once you step outside marriage you are stepping into a slippery morally uncharted territory which offers no guarantee for a healthy and efficient human conduct.

However, if you view premarital relations as a sort of "test ride" for marriage, then there are Islamic ways of making sure you love the person you want to marry before marriage. In Islam the two families can meet and talk together as much as they want before and at some point they can allow the boy and the girl to talk directly together. In some cultures, if they have an initial positive view of one another then they even are allowed to go out with one another but while observing all religious limits such as not touching, observing hijab, etc. In the advance stages of marriage proposal, like the sides are like 90% sure about the marriage, the boy and the girl can even see one another's body in some controlled way.

In some Muslim societies, the couples can also go to marriage consultants and see whether the couples fit one another by having interviews and filling out questionnaires.

So if getting to know one another is the issue there can be a lot of Islamic solutions to it. Some of it depends on the intelligence and ijtihad of the scholars and some of it on different Muslim cultures. But I think all Muslims can look at the case of Prophet Muhammad and Lady Khadija (sawa) who knew and met each other for a long time before Lady Khadija (sawa) asked for the Prophet's hand. Prophet (as) used to work for Khadija as a trade partner and in the process Khadija (as) could test his life skills and integrity and learn about his exceptional moral character. Now based on this shared Islamic tradition, we can expect Muslims to allow a safe, Islamically moderated chance for couples to know another before nikah.

Other obstacles you named such as financial instability or not wanting to have children, one can think of Islamic solutions to them too. Parents may help a boy with financial instability or allow the couples to live with them for some time until they become stable. However, not having children at all though is strongly discouraged by Islam because it has long term negative consequences both for the couples and the society.

Having said that I should note brotherly and sisterly love among males and females in Islam is in fact a virtue. All men and women should ideally love one another the way they love their genetic brothers and sisters. But this love is different from sexual or genetic love both in motivation and expression and takes place within all laws governing relations between non-mahram individuals in Islam. This is the kind of love that motivated Muslim women in early days of Islam to aid the unrelated Muslim men during jihad, or the kind of love which Sumayya bint Khabbat had for the Prophet of Islam (as) and Allah which led to her martyrdom. This is a love that emerges from our souls not our bodies and is likewise directed to one another's souls not bodies. We are all created from one self or soul after all despite being genetically and tribally distinct.

Comment: How exactly is it "morally slippery"? Also what if you dont want to have kids? If the purpose of marriage is procreation but you dont want to procreate then cant it be done outside marriage because other factors of marriage are still present as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AAAAAOOOOO Like I said the general purpose is procreation but even without procreation, you can still marry. Why do you want to avoid the legal framework? By slippery or uncharted, I meant a kinda of relationship that is not regulated by law or moral norms of Islam and is therefore unpredictable and risky.

Comment: Yes but that is the question why is the legal framework so important that marriage is essential and anything outside marriage is so haram and bad that some even compare it to the likes of theft etc. Also relationships outside marriage couldve been regulated by law but why isnt it why is marriage so important. Also if you have a reference to these moral norms that you have in marriage but not outside other than children (which you can also have outside marriage) please reference it.

Comment: Relationships outside marriage may be regulated by governments but no longer based on Islamic law but secular law. A person engaging in non-marital relations won't be observant of Islamic law any way and there wouldn't be any spiritual motivation involved. In Islam, marriage is both a contract and a religious commitment and religious families are usually more stable as likely there's less selfishness and materialism.

Comment: Do you have any proof for your last claim? Also that still doesnt answer what the moralities and responsibilities of marriage there are that lead relatinships outside marriage to be so haram and inside amrriage to be so important. Also regarding the procreation thing you havent answered what the problem is with people who dont want to procreate and why marriage is important here. Assuming they all have the same responsibilities and there is stability in the relationship also lets say a promise has been made not to leave why is marriage important here.

Comment: @AAAAAOOOOO You are already saying that you are not interested in procreation which is already a compromise of Islamic moral norms. Other norms are the ones I mentioned in my last statement. which doesn't need "proof" if you are looking for empirical confirmation because, it's rather an analytic statement: less selfishness = greater care. Less materialism = greater interest in moral and spiritual qualities of the spouse and less tendency to extravagance and vanity = better relations.

Comment: Yes but how exactly do you know that islamic marriages cause people to be less selfish with certainty because from the people I have been a wtiness to the marriages are the same as those of non-Muslims. Also just because procreation is supposed to be part of Islams moral norms doesnt make it obligatory and it is not needed in marriage so what if a couple doesnt want to procreate then what is the difference between that relationship and ones outside marriage assuming that they are committed, same chance of divorce etc. Also relationships outside marriage arent always extravagant.

Comment: @AAAAAOOOOO It's not just about the marriage part in Islam, it's the impact of overall heartfelt dedicated religious observance on life. If you are marrying outside Islam, it already means you are not religiously observant and the dislike of children is another confirmation. It's what it boils down to.

Comment: That is just not correct> Disliking children and not having a desire to have children are two completely different things. It is not obligatory to have kids and some may not want to either due to financial position etc. Also I know people who have relationships outside of marriage (without sex) who are religiously committed. But you still havent answered the question that I mentioned above about why marriage is so important even for people who dont want to procreate assuming they are in the same situation as a couple of marriage (same chance of divorce etc).

Comment: @AAAAAOOOOO The problem is if you think they are really identical I don't see why you insist on marrying outside Islam, then? I think we can move on.

Comment: Because it is a lot easier to have a relationship outside of marriage. The points I mentioned in the question regarding why marriage may be difficult shows that not to mention there may be others too. If the situations are identical then why does Islam insist on making something so similar so different (in terms of punishment/holiness (if that is the correct word)) to the point where one can lead you to hell whereas the other is perfectly fine.

Comment: @AAAAAOOOOO Nikah is holy due to the fact that it is the Allah-sanctioned form of marriage and that it starts with Godly intentions and prayers. So there's a spiritual spirit involved that kinda sanctifies the people involved in it. And because of its sacred spirit the marriage is likely more stable and the couples less likely to tend to divorce. Prophet Muhammad (as) has described divorce as the most undesirable of Allah's permissions.

Comment: Well (not to be rude) but it doesnt seem to be working spiritually because lots of families have divorces and also Im not asking what makes marriage so important im asking why. Please can you still answer the procreation thing that I have mentioned, why is there such major punishment if you dont want to procreate but want to have a relationship and cant marry due to X,Y or Z if they are basically the same thing (assuming same chances of divorce etc).

Comment: @AAAAAOOOOO What I am telling you is not based on confirmation from our today's troubled Muslim world but from how an ideal Muslim life must look like. Yes, there are "Muslim" families who look more unhealthy than secular families. But we should look to our ideal paradigms. Think of long-term consequences of not having children: societies age, nursing homes for the elderly not looked after by any children, elderly depression, economic recession, governments rather than your own family inheriting the wealth you have obtained after a life-long career.

Comment: Ok but then why cant you have children outside of amrriage if they are in essence "identical" assuming there are same chances of breakup/divorce etc. What makes marriage so important that if you were to live the exact same life as you would married but without being married you could go to hell. Some people aren't as fortunate to be able to marry so why is marriage so important if the outcome of a marriage and without can be the same then as well. Also regarding not having kids im not talking about everyone im talking about some people with exceptiomns. There are also negatives to procreation

Comment: E.g financial reasons, stability in family, homelessness due to lack of houses etc this could also lead to mental impacts and so on.